# Facing a problem with making a table in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, sumifs, cumulative-sum

I am making a sheet to oversee funds
I am trying to make something like this in Google Sheets

D(n) = D(n-1) + B(n) - C(n)  for the entire row of D

[image: Sample sheet]

and so on for the entire row
I also would prefer if the remaining fund didn't show up unless a value for received or spent has been input

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a duplicate exactly as you want to add one column and subtract the other whereas the original question was just about adding one column. Never mind, strange things happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUMIF to get running totals of columns B and C, and subtract one from the other:

```
=ArrayFormula(if((B3:B="")*(C3:C=""),"",sumif(row(A3:A),"<="&row(A3:A),B3:B)-sumif(row(A3:A),"<="&row(A3:A),C3:C)+D2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((B3:B)+(C3:C), 
 MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(B3:B)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B3:B)))*B3:B), SIGN(B3:B))+D2-
 MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(C3:C)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(C3:C)))*C3:C), SIGN(C3:C)), IFERROR(1/0)))
```

[image: 0]